# How can I calculate the exact solution to a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let us consider a differential equation of the form :

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} +  a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$$
The solution is of the form $u = c_0 + c_1\exp(ax)$. Wtih boundary conditions $u(\infty) = 0.5$ and $u(0) = -bV$. Here, b and V are constants. How do I now calculate the exact solution of this differential equation ?

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. The auxiliary equation formed would be
$$m^2+am=0$$
$$m(m+a)=0$$
$$m=0,\, -a$$
$$\therefore u=c_0+c_1 e^{-ax}$$
Assuming that $a\gt 0$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$u(\infty)=c_0=0.5$$
But one cannot determine the exact solution without another boundary condition. So the final solution is then
$$u=0.5+c e^{-ax}$$

Comment: @Terence, don't add things to the answer that wasn't the author's intent. If you think there are steps missing, write a comment, or better, post your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in another answer, the generic solution to

$\frac{d^2 u}{d x^2} +  a\frac{d u}{d x} = 0$

for $a \ne 0$ is actually

$u = c_0 + c_1\exp(-ax)$

As long as $a>0$ then we have

$u(0) = c_0 \\ u(\infty) = c_0+c_1 \\ \Rightarrow c_1 = u(\infty) - u(0)$

If $a<0$ then $u(\infty)$ is undefined as $u$ is unbounded as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

If $a=0$ then the generic solution is $u=c_0+c_1x$ and again $u(\infty)$ is undefined.